# WPF: How do I bind to an ICommand defined in a control?

Tags: wpf

My control has a property that returns an ICommand object. Using XAML, how to I bind a button to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the relation of the two I would use element binding. E.g.

```
<YourControl x:Name="CmdSrc" />
<Button Command={Binding ElementName=CmdSrc, Path=CmdProperty} />
```

You should think about the approach that a control provides a command. It's seems to me some kind of weird. ;)

Regards

**EDIT**

Ah ok, it was just a hint. Just in case you didn't think about it.

Here is another way to bind your command. I've to admit that I didn't test it. But I think the following should work too.

When the `Button` is in the control you could also use relative binding.

```
<YourControl>
  <Button Command={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourControl}}, Path=CmdProperty} />
</YourControl>
```

Then you don't need a name for the control. I'm avoiding names when ever I can to prevent dirty workarounds in code behind.

Yes, I know it some kind of paranoid. ;)

Comment: The button is on the control that has the command. The sole purpose is to affect UI elements, so the normal Model or ViewModel patterns don't fit.

Comment: How about that, I didn't expect to be able to tag the top-level UserControl element with an x:Name. But it worked like a charm.

Comment: Interesting. I do believe your edit will also fix some other problems I've been dealing with.